# Type deduction in switch and SFINAE, gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang++

I've noticed a difference in behavior between Clang and GCC with following code:

```
class convertible {
public:
    operator int() { return 1; }

    template <typename T>
    operator T() { return 1; }
};


int main () {
    convertible x;
    switch (x) {}  // Clang: OK   GCC: Compile error
    return 0;
}
```

GCC returns `error: default type conversion can't deduce template argument for ‘template<class T> convertible::operator T()’`

Clang compiles code without errors and calls `operator int()`

I'm using Clang 6 and GCC 8.  Both with std=c++11

Which compiler is correct in this case?

Comment: Where's SFINAE?

Comment: MSVC compiles it too.

Comment: @geza I'm not an expert, but I think that second case can be disabled because T is invalid. But I don't really know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @random I think what you've mentioned is more overload resolution. But very interesting question!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the type `switch` will try to convert `convertible` to guaranteed? Is it guaranteed to be `int` or just some integral type? Does it depend on the `case` labels? If so, what happens here when there is no `case` label?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Not guaranteed. Just some integral or enumeration type: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch#2

Comment: I'd say clang is correct. `int` is an integral type, so there is no need to instantiate `operator T()` with any `T`. Yes W.F., good question :)

Comment: I vaguely remember some words in the standard that template conversion operators won't be considered for switch based type conversion.  This is only a vague memory, but if someone finds it it will pretty much prove that gcc screwed up.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: that would be logical, as there is no definite type to instantiate with. An integral type can be anything.

Comment: @geza Yes: the duplicate target is what I was talking about.  Looks like gcc is enumerating the conversion operators to find an integral one; and it shouldn't be enumerating the template ones.  But because it does, it dies as it cannot determine if `operator T` is an integral conversion operator or not.